# What is difference between <? extends Object> and <E extends Object>?

Tags: java, generics

What is difference between `<? extends Object>` and `<E extends Object>` ?
When should one be used over the other?

Comment: You can reuse `E`.

Comment: They are mutually exclusive.

Comment: IMO I would use `<? extends AClassOrInterface>` in `static` utility methods to process the elements of a collection (set, list, map, etc) and nothing more, and I would use `<E extends MyClass>` for class/interface definition in case I want the fields (field of type E or a collection filled with elements of type E).

Answer (score 16):

Here are some differences that immediately comes to my mind:

- Type parameter bounds can specify multiple bounds - `T extends A & B`, but with wildcard you cannot specify multiple bounds - `? extends A & B` is invalid.
- You can have lower bounds with wildcard - `? super A` is valid, but not with the type parameter - `T super A` is not valid.
- You cannot use wildcard bounds while creating a generic type. You have to use type parameter bounds.
- Inside a method, if you want some relation between the type parameters of arguments passed, then you have to use type parameter bounds. For e.g, you want to pass two parameterized type with same type parameter. You can't do this with wildcard bounds. So the following method declaration will take two list of same type parameter, that extends `Number`.

  ```
  public <T extends Number> void merge(List<T> list1, List<T> list2) {
  }
  ```

To end with, I'll add some points from *Effective Java - Item 28: Use bounded wildcards to increase API flexibility*:

> For maximum flexibility, use wildcard types on input parameters that represent producers or consumers. If an input parameter is both a producer and a consumer, then wildcard types will do you no good: you need an exact type match, which is what you get without any wildcards.
>
> Do not use wildcard types as return types. Rather than providing additional flexibility for your users, it would force them to use wildcard types in client code. Properly used, wildcard types are nearly invisible to users of a class. They cause methods to accept the parameters they should accept and reject those they should reject. **If the user of a class has to think about wildcard types, there is probably something wrong with the class’s API.**

---

**References:**

- [Angelika Langer - JavaGenericsFAQ](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/JavaGenericsFAQ.html)

  - [What is a bounded type parameter?](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TypeParameters.html#What%20is%20a%20bounded%20type%20parameter?)
  - [What is a wildcard bound?](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TypeArguments.html#What%20is%20a%20wildcard%20bound?)

Answer (score 6):

`<? extends Object>` is a *bounded wildcard* (an unknown that extends `Object` , whereas  `<E extends Object>` is type bounded (`E` requires a Parameterized type that extends `Object`).

Most subtle differences of *bounded wildcards* from the parameterized upper bound:

- Bounded wildcards cannot be used when creating Generic type classes, only typed parameters are allowed.
- Bounded wildcards cannot be used in `Collection`s where it requires to add items in the a collection, as it is an unknown type, and the collection doesn't know what type it is receiving, hence it is not type safe.
- Bounded wildcards cannot be bounded to multiple generic types (bounds).

I hope this helps.

Comment: both `<? extends Object>` and `<E extends Object>` are bounded, they have upper bound `Object`

Comment: Actually using wildcards in Collections where it requires to add items can be done if the wildcard is of the type <? super SomeClass>

Comment: @Lorenzo Baracchi, indeed, but that is not what was asked here though. :-)

Comment: @BuhakeSindi actually again, your second point is wrong in the sense of difference, there doesnt remain any difference thus or "type bounded can be used in Collections where it requires to add items in a collection..." Care to explain?

Comment: @manocha_ak, simple: Create a simple example: `Collection<? extend Object> collection = new ArrayList<? extends Object>();`. Now, add an item. If you're using Eclipse IDE, you will see it says, `collection.add(null e)`. That's what I mean. `?` is a wildcard unbounded and that's what I addressed on the post.

Answer (score 5):

Use `E` if you need to refer to the type later on. Use `?` if you never have to refer to the type again.

Answer (score 0):

In generic code, the question mark (?), called the wildcard, represents an unknown type. The wildcard can be used in a variety of situations: as the type of a parameter, field, or local variable; sometimes as a return type (though it is better programming practice to be more specific). The wildcard is never used as a type argument for a generic method invocation, a generic class instance creation, or a supertype. For more info check [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/upperBounded.html)

Answer (score -1):

`<E>` declares a type argument.
You can only use it when creating a generic type or method.

`<? ...>` is a wildcard *value* of a type argument.
You can only use it when creating a closed generic type.