# Generics methods - passing objects and invoking its method

Tags: java, generics

I'm trying to understand how Generics works and wrote a method to test it.

I have created Object - Drink and its child object Coffee... and defined a generic method go1() to invoke the sip() method of both these objects...

I'm running in Eclipse and get an error - stating the method sip() is undefined for type V.

Can someone explain how this is handled?

```
class Drink{
    public void sip(){
        System.out.println("Im Drink method");
    }
}

class Coffee extends Drink{
    public void sip(){
        System.out.println("Im Coffee method");
    }

}

public class test{

    public static <V> V go1(V o){
        o.sip();

    }

public static <V> void go(V v){
        System.out.println(v.hashCode());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Drink s1 = new Drink();
        go1(s1);

            int i = 10;
        String j ="test";
        go(i);
        go(j);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add bounds to the type parameter:

```
public static <V extends Drink> void go1(V o){
    o.sip();
}
```

With type parameter bound, you get access to the non-static methods of the bound - `Drink` in this case, using the reference of that type parameter.

**After edit:**

For passing `String` and `Integer` to your method, you can think of which common upper bound would fit for both. The common supertype for `String` and `Integer` are:

- [`Object`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html)
- [`Serializable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html)
- [`Comparable<T>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html)

So, you can have three kinds of bounds:

- `<V extends Object>`
- `<V extends Serializable>`
- `<V extends Comparable<V>>`

So you just modify your `go()` method like:

```
public static <V extends Object> void go(V v){
    System.out.println(v.hashCode());
}
```

**References:**

- [Java Generics FAQs](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/Features.html)

  - [What is type parameter bounds?](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TypeParameters.html#What%20is%20a%20type%20parameter%20bound?)
- [What is difference between <? extends Object> and <E extends Object>?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18384897/1679863)

Comment: It worked fine..Can you please explain how go() method can alone handle both Integer and String data types?

Comment: @user1050619. Think of what is the common supertype of both `Integer` and `String`? Give that type as upper bound. For example `Object`.

Comment: Isn't Object is also supertype of DRINK?

Comment: @user1050619. Yes. But that is not related to this issue.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that plain `<V>` can't be understood as a `Drink` but as a generic `Object`. You need to bind the generic to your `Drink` class, so declare the generic as `<V extends Drink>`.

More info: [Generic Methods and Bounded Type Parameters](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/boundedTypeParams.html)

Answer (score 1):

The compiler decides if method calls are valid based on the type they are called on. You have

```
public static <V> V go1(V o){
    o.sip();
}
```

but `V` is not a bounded type so the compiler can only be sure that it is at least of type `Object`. `Object` doesn't have a `sip()` method. You need to bound your type

```
public static <V extends Drink> V go1(V o){
    o.sip();
}
```

This way the compiler knows that `V` is at least of type `Drink`. `Drink` has a `sip()` method.

Answer (score 1):

**Just to aid your understanding..**

Given that your overall objective is to further your understanding of Generics, I'd just like to point out that a simple interface or superclass object reference would be a simpler solution to your issue. i.e:

```
public void go1(Drink d)
{
    d.sip();
}
```

**A more classic example of Generics**

Let's say you've got an object, `Pair`. Pair needs to be able to hold two of anything in Java, so you make those two things of type `Object`. What does that mean? It means you're *always* casting between `Object` and the desired type. So what do you do? You use generics.

```
public class Pair<F,S>
{
     F first;
     S second;

     public Pair(F first, S second)
     { 
          this.first = first;
          this.second = second;
     }
}
```

Now instead of having to cast, you simply state:

```
Pair<Integer, String> pair = new Pair<Integer, String>(10, "Ten");
```