# Java: Map of objects that extend and implement

Tags: java, generics

I'm trying to make a map of objects that both implement and extend.  The class they are extending (JPanels) I have no control over. I do, however, have control over the interface.

This is what I've tried

```
Map<MyEnum, ? extends JPanel & MyInterface> myMap;
```

That, however, is a compile time error.

I could make an abstract class and then make the subclasses extend it, but that seems a bit heavy handed (or is it?).

For the record, I'm using Java 6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> That, however, is a compile time error.

Yes. You can't give multiple bounds to wildcards. There is some restriction on where you can use wildcards, and where you can use type parameters. Type parameters can have multiple bounds, but they can't have lower bounds. Wildcards on the other hand, can have lower bounds, but they don't have multiple bounds.

One option is to have the type parameter declared as a part of your class, and give multiple bounds to it:

```
class MyClass<T extends JPanel & MyInterface> {
    Map<MyEnum, T> myMap;  // This would work fine now
}
```

**See also:**

- [What is difference between <? extends Object> and <E extends Object>?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18384897/1679863)

**References:**

- [Angelika Langer's - Java Generics FAQs](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/JavaGenericsFAQ.html)

  - [What is a type parameter bound?](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TypeParameters.html#What%20is%20a%20type%20parameter%20bound?)
  - [What is the difference between a wildcard bound and a type parameter bound?](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TypeArguments.html#What%20is%20the%20difference%20between%20a%20wildcard%20bound%20and%20a%20type%20parameter%20bound?)

Answer (score 1):

> I could make an abstract class and then make the subclasses extend it, but that seems a bit heavy handed (or is it?).

Not at all: this should work just fine.

Another approach is to add an interface that combines the methods of `JPanel` of interest to your methods that use `myMap`, and use it like this:

```
interface MyPanelInterface extends MyInterface {
    void    updateUI();
}
...
class MySpecialPanel extends JPanel implements MyPanelInterface {
    ...
    // Implementation for updateUI() comes from JPanel
    // You are responsible for implementing the remaining methods.
}
...
Map<MyEnum, ? extends MyPanelInterface> myMap;
...
myMap.get(MyEnum.FIRST).updateUI();
```

Answer (score 1):

You should create your own class that extends the JPanel and implements MyInterface as you too suggested, then use  `Map<? extends MyNewSuperClass> myMap;`

Answer (score 0):

I never had to do this, but as you suggested you may go ahead and create a new class or interface (based on your need) implementing/extending the interfaces/classes you need and then use it in your Map.

Public Interface IWhatIneed implements Jpanel, MyInterface{
...
}

and then:

```
Map<MyEnum, ? extends JPanel & MyInterface> myMap;
```

I hope this would help