# Java: List of objects that extends/implements two classes/interfaces

Tags: java, generics

I need to have a `List` that holds objects that extends class X, and implements interface Y.

I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19305627/java-map-of-objects-that-extend-and-implement), but I realized it's not really what I need.

Consider this:

```
class Test<T extends MyBaseClass & MyBaseInterface>
{
    public List<T> myList;
}

public abstract class MyBaseClass {}
public interface MyBaseInterface {}
public class MyDerivedClassA extends MyBaseClass implements MyBaseInterface {}
public class MyDerivedClassB extends MyBaseClass implements MyBaseInterface {}

Test<MyDerivedClassA> obj = new Test<MyDerivedClassA>();
obj.myList.add(new MyDerivedClassA()); // Works
obj.myList.add(new MyDerivedClassB()); // Compile error
```

This will make `obj.myList` into a `List<MyDerivedClassA>` at compile time. What I need is to have `myList` hold a list of objects that can be of **any class**, provided it extends `MyBaseClass` **and** implements `MyBaseInterface`. It means that in the example, `myList.add(new MyDerivedClassB())` should work.

#### Another Example

This example is closer to what I need.

```
public abstract class Animal {}
public abstract class Mammal extends Animal {}
public abstract class Bird extends Animal {}

public class Tiger extends Mammal {}
public class Ostrich extends Bird {}

public interface RunningObject {}
public class RunningTiger extends Tiger implements RunningObject {}
public class RunningOstrich extends Ostrich implements RunningObject {}
public class RunningRobot extends NonAnimal implements RunningObject {}

// This line is syntactically wrong
public List<Animal & RunningObject> runningAnimals = new List<>();

runningAnimals.add(new RunningTiger()); // This should work
runningAnimals.add(new RunningOstrich()); // This should work
runningAnimals.add(new Tiger()); // This should give compile error
runningAnimals.add(new Ostrich()); // This should give compile error
runningAnimals.add(new RunningRobot()); // This should give compile error
```

What I need is to achieve type safety at compile time. This question is about Java and Generics, so please don't give me answer regarding things like design pattern (i.e. using Strategy design pattern).

Comment: Class MyDerivedClassB is not MyDerivedClassA.
Try 'Test<MyBaseInterface> obj = new Test<>();'

Answer (score 2):

If you can control access to the list, you can make the list simply hold instances of `MyBaseClass`, but then only add to the list via a special method with the extra constraint:

```
private List<MyBaseClass> list;

<T extends MyBaseClass & MyBaseInterface> boolean add(T e) {
  return list.add(e);
}
```

Now, you, as the author of the class, know that all of the instances in the list can be safely cast to `MyBaseInterface`, as well as using them as `MyBaseClass` directly.

This is quite janky, but it's fine to do casting of the elements *if you must*, provided you take responsibility for ensuring their safety - the compiler can only do so much.

Comment: `&` operator doesn't work for `?` wildcard, otherwise I would not have wrapped the list with a `Test` class.

Comment: @Jai ok, i removed the first two options.

Comment: This means I cannot directly expose the list outside of the class, and I have to manually write all the methods of the list that I want to expose to outside of this class?

Comment: Thanks. This is technically the correct approach, but in practical it is hard for me to implement this. I definitely want to directly expose a list that can take in correct compile-time objects via methods like `list.add()`.

Answer (score 0):

Introduce a "mid-level" abstract class:

```
class Test<T extends MyBaseClass & MyBaseInterface>
{
    public List<T> myList;
}

abstract class MyBaseClass {}
interface MyBaseInterface {}
class MyDerivedClassA extends DerivedClass {}
class MyDerivedClassB extends DerivedClass {}
class DerivedClass extends MyBaseClass implements MyBaseInterface {}
```

You can then go with

```
Test<DerivedClass> obj = new Test<>();
obj.myList.add(new MyDerivedClassA()); // Works
obj.myList.add(new MyDerivedClassB()); // Works
```

Comment: This is near to what I was asking, but my actual problem is actually more complex than this. See updated question.